# Rename named parameter in Python to avoid naming conflicts with import statement

Tags: python, import, python-import

Say I have a function `foo` in a big Python project that has a named argument `bar`:

```
def foo(bar=42):
  do_something_with_bar(bar)
```

This function is called a lot in the codebase, in calls that use or omit the named `bar` parameter.

Now say I'm changing this function because it has a bug and want start using a function from a certain package, that is coincidentally also called `bar`. I cannot use the `bar` function when I import it like this:

```
from package import bar

def foo(bar=42):
  # how can I use the package.bar function here?
  do_something_with_bar(bar)
```

I could use something like:

```
from package import bar as package_bar
```

But this file also contains a lot of invocations of `bar` so that's a no-go.

The only way I can see this working is to rename the `bar` method from `package`:

```
from package import bar
package_bar = bar

def foo(bar=42):
  do_something_with_bar(package_bar(bar))
```

Or to import it multiple times (untested):

```
from package import bar, bar as package_bar

def foo(bar=42):
  do_something_with_bar(package_bar(bar))
```

Is there some way I can rename the `bar` parameter in the `foo` function, without all calls to the `foo` function breaking in the entire codebase?

Answer (score 7):

This is a common issue. In this case, it helps to have an additional import statement for `package`, so you can safely refer to `package`'s `bar` through the `package` namespace without running into naming conflicts.

```
import package
from package import bar

def foo(bar=42):
    do_something_with_bar(package.bar(bar))
```

You still end up importing the module once, but you now have two ways of referring to `bar`.

Comment: @Idlehands I think OP's problem is that they have a function `bar` and an argument `bar` that they want to be able to refer to within the same function `foo` with minimal headache. The name clash isn't an issue anywhere but inside `foo`, I assume.

Comment: Thanks, I had to reread the question and answer twice.  I was genuinely confused about why OP was against `from package import bar as package_bar`, but seeing your answer now I understand there are instances *outside of foo* that he also wants to maintain.  Thanks for the clarification.  In this case I might even say just a `import package` would suffice, but I digress :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace the function body with a call to another function with differently named arguments:

```
from package import bar

def foo(bar=42):
    return _foo(baz=bar)

def _foo(baz):
    do_something_with_bar(bar(baz))
```

Then you are free to use `bar` in that function as the name of the function from the package rather than the argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky, the foo function is only called by "foo()" or "foo(24)" and nowhere by "foo(bar=42)" and then you can put any new name instead of bar without breaking anything.
Else you have to grep / search for all calls of "foo(bar=" and replace them too, being careful of the possible extra spaces like in "foo( bar =".

Comment: OP writes "calls [...] use or omit the named bar parameter."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but if you just wanna avoid namespace conflict in that specific function, why not import it inside the function?

```
def foo(bar=42):
  from package import bar as package_bar
  do_something_with_bar(package_bar(bar))
```

And you can add one line comment at top to remind yourself.

Comment: Importing inside a function is generally discouraged and will make pylint complain.

Comment: Yes it is. But there is a reason. That makes it difficult to identify what packages are used in this file. So I mentioned that you can use comment to notify.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) to reference global variables.

```
def foo(bar=42):
    package_bar = globals()['bar']
    do_something_with_bar(package_bar(bar))
```

This shouldn't break anything in your code base.

Comment: Having anything to do with globals() and locals() is bad practice except in the rarest of cases. I don't know if this counts.

Comment: Okey, didn't know this as I never had to use them, but this (and making a wrapper function) seems to be the only way to prevent double imports just for reference's sake.